# bunch of error after creating a new project with the first person template

Tags: unity-game-engine

Just updated unity hub to the last version, created a new project with the template "first template" that I just downloaded, then when creating it asked me if I wanted to go in safe mode, and showed me a bunch of error like that

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@10.9.0\Runtime\XR\XRSystem.cs(142,25): error CS1061: 'XRDisplaySubsystem' does not contain a definition for 'BeginRecordingIfLateLatched' and no accessible extension method 'BeginRecordingIfLateLatched' accepting a first argument of type 'XRDisplaySubsystem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried to update my packages since I saw someone saying that on another post but not sure if it was actually same as my problem, didn't solved it at least.